# WPF Async Binding Validation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, idataerrorinfo

I'm running into a issue, where anytime after the first time a load a new tab in my wpf application, the IDataValidationInfo template is being shown, for no reason.

My Error Template:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">            
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1.25"
         BorderBrush="#FFDC000C" CornerRadius="2">
            <Grid>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Popup x:Name="placard"
         AllowsTransparency="True"
         PopupAnimation="Fade"
         Placement="Top"
         PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=adorner}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:RepositionPopupBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Popup.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=errorShape, Path=IsMouseOver}"
                       Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <!-- Hides Popup when window is no longer active -->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=IsActive}"
                       Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Popup.Style>
            <Border x:Name="errorBorder"
            Background="#FFDC000C"
            Margin="0,0,8,8"
            Opacity="1"
            CornerRadius="4"
            IsHitTestVisible="False"
            MinHeight="24"
            MaxWidth="267">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4"
                          Color="Black"
                          Opacity="0.6"
                          Direction="315"
                          BlurRadius="4"/>
                </Border.Effect>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner, Path=AdornedElement.Validation.Errors[0].ErrorContent}"
                 Foreground="White"
                 Margin="8,3,8,3"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
        <Ellipse DockPanel.Dock="Right" Name="errorShape"
                        IsHitTestVisible="True"
                         Width="8" Height="8"
                         Margin="1,0,0,0"
                         StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red" >
            <Ellipse.Stroke>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFA0404" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC9C7C7" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Stroke>
        </Ellipse>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

So the first time I add the user control to the tab, It doesn't show the errors, which it shouldn't because the required fields are filled in.
[image]

I close the tab, and go into a different user, the validation fires for no reason.
[image]

Its supposed to look like this, but it shouldn't even be firing when it does in the picture above, because the required fields are filled. Its also not showing the error message.

Below is what it should look like when there are no values, which does work.
[image]

I'm loading the data that populates these fields async, shown below.
Why does it work the first time I load the user control? But every time after that it shows an error when there is none? Is there some sort of WPF cache? Is the adorner layer not getting disposed?

```
public exampleVM:IDataErrorInfo
{

 public exampleConstructor()
  {
    Populate();
  }

  public async Task Populate()
  {
   //Async Call to DB, Fill in the VM Fields from result, 
   //EX:firstname,lastname
  }
}
```

Comment: could you show me your user control xaml code? Did you set the UpdateSourceTrigger property to "PropertyChanged"?

Comment: <TextBox MinWidth="150" Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"></TextBox>

Comment: I feel like it has to do with async, but I can't figure out what the deal is.